# Issue decrypting and zipping in Camel

Tags: java, encryption, zip, apache-camel

### Question

I have a camel route that reads 4 xml files and encrypts them using camel crypto. I have another route that picks up these encrypted files, decrypts and saves them to file system. It works absolutely fine.

However, I have a requirement to decrypt and zip these files in a single camel route. I haven't been able to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted to read a '1347093252' byte initialization vector from inputStream but only '6016' bytes were retrieved
                at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.CryptoDataFormat.getInlinedInitializationVector(CryptoDataFormat.java:193)

WARN  AggregateProcessor             - Error processing aggregated exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is file based: /tmp/camel-tmp-342373/camel4393278949787760082.zip]]. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - Error reading initialization vector from encrypted stream]
java.io.IOException: Error reading initialization vector from encrypted stream
                at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.CryptoDataFormat.getInlinedInitializationVector(CryptoDataFormat.java:197)
                at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.CryptoDataFormat.unmarshal(CryptoDataFormat.java:152)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:65)
                at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
```

### Route

```
<camel:crypto id="cry" keyRef="secretKey" algorithm="AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" initVectorRef="iv" inline="true" 
      shouldAppendHMAC="false" />

<camel:route>
       <camel:from uri="file:/opt/vipin/abc/dec?include=.*.xml&amp;noop=true" />
             <camel:marshal ref="cry" />
             <camel:to uri="file:/opt/vipin/abc/enc?doneFileName=test.done" />
</camel:route>

<camel:route>
     <camel:from uri="file:/opt/vipin/abc/enc?  
          include=.*.xml&amp;noop=true&amp;doneFileName=test.done" />
     <camel:aggregate strategyRef="zipAggregationStrategy"    
        completionFromBatchConsumer="true" completionSize="4">
      <camel:correlationExpression>
       <camel:constant>true</camel:constant>
     </camel:correlationExpression>
    <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.io.File" />
    <camel:unmarshal ref="cry" />
    <camel:to uri="file:/opt/vipin/abc/dec?fileName=abc.zip" />
 </camel:aggregate>
</camel:route>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am currently maintaining the application you have worked on in the past. And occasionally I still see the above mentioned error. When I googled with the error this is the only post I found on the web :)  Small world!

I think the problem is caused when different Java Keystore is used to decrypt files.  e.g. I have encryted file in a JVM which has Keystore 1 using certificate Cert1 . And then tried to decrypt it in a different JVM which has Keystore 2 and a different certificate with same name: Cert1. i.e certificate name is same but key is different.

In this case JVM tries to load and decrypt using "Cert1" but not able to do so. That is the reason the number of bytes on header is not equivalent to the number of bytes in the body. In this case I expected more a suitable error, I agree that the above error is misleading.

Hope this clears some confusion!